# Disposable custom controls in Xamarin.Forms/MAUI

Tags: user-interface, xamarin.forms, idisposable, maui

Many tutorials and guides suggest that when you create a custom control in Xamarin.Forms or .NET MAUI with a `ContentView` (or extending another view), it should implement `IDisposable` interface when needed. See [here](https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/ways-create-netmaui-controls#3-using-contentview) and [here](https://xamgirl.com/tips-and-ticks-when-creating-a-custom-control-in-xamarin-forms-part-1/).

That can be useful, as far as i can see, to unsubscribe from events.

My question is: when is `Dispose()` called?

I tried some scenarios in Xamarin.Forms involving moving from the page where the custom view lies and removing that page from the navigation stack, but none of these actions called the `Dispose()` method.
Do I have to call it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have to do it manually.

Javier Suarez answered this question with a [Youtube comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8d7xLErPm9o&lc=UgzXYwxHY79uanaQVTF4AaABAg&ab_channel=JavierSu%C3%A1rez) under his video.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Unsubscribe from the message in the message action/handler, or use a pattern of subscribing in OnAppearing and unsubscribing in OnDisappearing.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string, DetailClass>(this, "NavigateDetail", async (detail) => 
{
   MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<string>(this, "NavigateDetail");
   await Naviation.PopAsync();
});
```

Comment: I wasn't actually asking for a "solution". I think you didn't get completely my question. It was about when a Disposable custom control is actually disposed. Thanks anyway.